# How to parameterize 'Synchronizing Timer' parameters in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to read synchronizing timer parameters value from csv file.

CSV file consists of two columns: Value and Count

I want to read 'Count' field value to parameterize 'Number of simulated users to group by field' .

I have tried :
1)${__BeanShell(1*${Count})}

2)${Count}

Comment: 2 should work, can you show your test plan?

Answer (score 0):

Add csv config file in your as child of your http request and add the following
[image]

and then add the following in sync timer

[image]

And your csv should look something like this

[image]

Comment: I am doing exactly like this. But its not working with ${Count}